# Attempt to read bb.size bytes from a specified address into the bytes_read array. But bytes_read remains the same before and after (Ghidra Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, ghidra

```py
address_to_read = bb.getMinAddress()

# Initialize a byte array to store the read bytes

bytes_read = bytearray(bb.size)

print("bytes_read before: ", bytes_read)

currentProgram = getCurrentProgram()

# Attempt to read bytes from the specified address into the byte array

num_bytes_read = currentProgram.getMemory().getBytes(address_to_read, bytes_read)

print("bytes_read after: ", bytes_read)
print("num_bytes_read: ", num_bytes_read)
```

bytes_read before:

```
bytearray(b'\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00')
```

bytes_read after:

```
bytearray(b'\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00')
num_bytes_read: 12
```

I've tried the following to initialize bytes_read:

- bytes_read = array.array('b', bytes_read)
- bytes_read = array.array("b", bytes(bytes_read))
- bytes_read = array.array('b', repr(bytes(bytes_read))[2:-1])
- bytes_read = array.array('b', bytes_read.decode('utf-8'))
- bytes_read = array.array('b', bytes_read.decode())
- bytes_read = list()*bb.size
- num_bytes_read = currentProgram.getMemory().getBytes(address_to_read, bytes_read, 0, bb.size)

None of them populate bytes_read.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that the memory area you're reading doesn't actually contain zeros?  Try initializing with something other than zeros, and see if the bytes change - `bytes_read = bytearray([65]) * bb.size` would give you an array of 'A's, for example.

Comment: bytes_read before:  bytearray(b'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA')
bytes_read after:  bytearray(b'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA')
num_bytes_read:  56

I am running my script for a program containing multiple functions. This is one of the many basic blocks in functions.

Comment: Has anyone tried using the int getBytes​(Address addr, byte[] b) method in their script and had their byte array populated as expected? I have yet to find any example codes to use the method. ref: https://ghidra.re/ghidra_docs/api/ghidra/program/database/mem/MemoryBlockDB.html#getBytes(ghidra.program.model.address.Address,byte%5B%5D)

Comment: I found https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/issues/858, it appears I have to use jarray. However, when trying to import jarray, it returns "import jarray
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jarray'". I cannot find the jarray package to install.

import jarray
bytes = jarray.array(bytes_read, "b")     

Could someone please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You explicitly claim to use Python 3, but Ghidra doesn't support that out of the box. What plugin are you using to run Python 3 code?

Comment: The plugin is Ghidrathon for Python 3.

Comment: @Herman try with ByteBuffer `bytes_read = java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(<size>)` and pass `bytes_read.array()` into `getBytes` method